# Вернуть ошибку при неверно введённом почтовом ящике

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Есть ajax-запрос:

```
$(function() {
    $('#backmail').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        var button = $('#backmail button[type="submit"]')
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'backmail.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
        }).done(function() {
            $form.slideUp('slow', function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $('#success-highlight').show();
        }).fail(function() {
            $form.slideUp('slow', function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
            $('#error-highlight').show();
        });
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

И есть PHP-скрипт, принимающий и отправляющий эти данные мне на почту:

```
<? 
    // config
    $adminemail="andrewdymov@gmail.com";
    $date=date("d.m.y");
    $time=date("H:i");

    // confirm data
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['mail']; 
    $subject = $_POST['subject']; 
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if (!preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/i", strtolower($email))) { header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"); } else { 
    $msg="<p>Отправлено: $time $date</p>
    <p>Имя: $name</p> 
    <p>E-mail: $email</p> 
    <p>Тема: $subject</p> 
    <p>Сообщение: $message</p>";  

    mail("$adminemail", "$subject", "$message"); } ?>
```

Суть проблемы заключается в том, что какую бы я абру-кадабру не писал в поле email, то данные к php-файлу всё равно отправляются успешно и php-скрипт возвращает код 200, хотя должен был бы вернуть мне 500. Я что-то сделал не так?

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта в чем проблема:

1. Файл php сохранен с UTF-8 BOM (либо стоит пробел перед `<?`) + выключены ошибки. Заголовки через header посылаются только если перед ними ничего не выводилось (в том числе UTF-8 BOM). Попробуйте включить ошибки (если они у вас выключены) и посмотреть.
2. В регулярном выражении нет ^ и $, соответственно достаточно совпадения регулярному выражению только части строчки. Например оно примет любую строчку, в которой есть "@t.t", например "тест тест тест @t.t". Возможно вы тестировали только варианты похожие на E-mail, так как просто "тест" не примет.

Comment: Я очень удивлён тому, что после <? не было написано php и скрипт из-за этого не работал. Дописал и всё прекрасным образом заработало.